# Querying with != and not-in throws error with Query.where in firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I tried using `!=` and `not-in` as params to `Query.where` as described [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#not_equal_):

```js
    db.collection("users")
      .where(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), "!=", curUser.uid)
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) => {
         ...
      });
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> Invalid value "!=" provided to function Query.where() for its second argument. Acceptable values: <, <=, ==, >=, >, array-contains, in, array-contains-any

I even tried this on an ordinary non-document id field and it gives the same error.

I am using the node package `firebase` version 7.9.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the latest version to be able to use not equal queries:

```
npm install firebase@8.0.0 --save
```

`!=` was released in version `7.21.0`:

https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#version_7210_-_september_17_2020